# Can anyone provide the counterexample for claim based on Summation of prime number having prime number of terms?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

***introducing s(k)***:

Here we first defined a symbol s(k) so that we could explain our observations in better manner.

When we wrote s(3) then it's means summation of 3 prime number and Similarly s(5) means summation of 5 prime numbers and so on.

---

***List of prime number from 2 to 401***:[Link for more prime number](https://jalu.ch/coding/primes/list.php#:%7E:text=There%20are%201229%20prime%20numbers,They%20are%20given%20here%20below)

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401

---

***Observation***:

s(2) = 2+3=5(prime number)

s(3) = 5+7+11 = 23(prime number)

s(5) = 13+17+19+23+29 = 101(prime number)

s(7) = 31+37+41+43+47+53+59 = 311(prime number)

s(11) = 61+67+71+73+79+83+89+
97+101+103+107 = 931(composite numbers)

s(13) = 109+113+127+131+137+
139+149+151+157+163+167+
173+179 = 1895(composite numbers)

s(17) = 181+191+193+197+199+
211+223+227+229+233+239+241+251+257+263+269+271 = 3875(composite numbers)

```
             :
             :
             :
```

s(Prime number) = .........

and so on.

***note***: We don't know any computer programming so that we could calculate such things for large number, we have checked this pattern upto s(37).

The value of
s(19)=6349(composite numbers)

```
         s(23)=10,643(composite numbers)

     
         s(29)=18,335(composite numbers)

     
         s(31)=25,873(composite numbers)

         s(37)=39,593(composite numbers)
```

---

***Claim***:

*My claim* : 2,3,5,7 are only ***consecutive prime numbers*** for which s(2);s(3);s(5);s(7) will be prime number?

*My friend Sankalp Savaran claim*: There may be ***infinately pairs or more than one pairs*** of ***Four consecutive Prime number*** $P_a; P_b ; P_c; P_d$ such that s($P_a$); s($P_b$); s($P_c$); s($P_d$) will be prime number?

---

***Question*** : Who's claim is correct here? And you can give counterexample to incorrect any of the two claim

Comment: @ShimuraVariety , in last ***Note*** we have wrote that , you can verify the correction of claim by giving counterexample also...., Suppose if you find other four consecutive prime number satisfying S(prime)=  Prime other than numbers ***2,3,5,7*** then my friends Sankalp Savaran claim seems more correct than me....., You can also provide answer like that....., I read on Wikipedia that proof regarding prime number are very complex so that's why we welcome example as answer also ..

Comment: The claims are not exhaustive. Which means that even if one such combination exists, only one statement is proven wrong and the other still may be wrong. Maybe that correction should also be made (i.e. it is possible both claims are wrong).

Comment: @Seeker , you can see list , i choose prime number one after one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137496/discussion-between-shimura-variety-and-jayendra-and-sankalp).

Comment: Considering that $s(p)$ only will grow polynomially with $p$ and that there should be no forced small factors, my guess is that there are infinite many solutions but that they are very rare. I highly doubt that we can find out whether this is true. But maybe we can find another example.

Comment: I upvoted because of the following reason : The definition of $s(p)$ is unusual, but from the list it is clear how it is calculated. Since the first four $s(p)$ are prime, but then follow many composites , it is natural to ask whether such a $4$-chain will occur again or even infinite many times. I cannot see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: Some quick (or maybe not so quick) computer searching: up to the five hundredth prime ($p_{500} = 3571$), there are a couple of doubles ($s(359), s(367)$ are both prime; as are $s(499), s(503)$;  $s(541), s(547)$; $s(2837), s(2842)$; and $s(3119), s(3121)$) but no chain of any longer length than that.

Comment: Here's a pattern for first terms of s(11) through s(23): (0 * 8) + 61 = 61; (6 * 8) + 61 = 109; (9 * 8) + (6 * 8) + 61 = 181; (12 * 8) + (9 * 8) + (6 * 8) + 61 = 277; (15 * 8) + (12 * 8) + (9 * 8) + (6 * 8) + 61 = 397 .

Comment: @Peter I suspect some of the down votes are because one has to reverse engineer the definition of $s(p)$ from the list.  I believe the definition $f(n)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{p_n-1} p_{m+j}$ where $m=1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i$ is more concise.

Comment: @StevenClark , very sorry Sir,  i am not a professional mathematician...so that why I don't able to think about how to write that expression of S(P) but i take some examples so that *readers could understand the pattern*

Comment: This conjecture has nothing to do with the Goldbach conjecture, so those links should be removed. Also I am confused what the largest known prime number has to do with this conjecture.

Comment: @Peter , as you see the probability of those 4 prime repeatation seems rare but if such repeatation is not discovered till largest known prime number then we have to beleive almost 99.99% that the *those 4 starting S(P) should be considered as unique...., However if anyone programming language don't allow them for  varyfying for large prime number then they could provide information as much they can verify upto maximum prime number....,And i have also removed the link of Goldbach conjecture but I put it as reference because in that conjecture sum prime also gives composite in most of cases ...

Comment: That's why we put it Link there but now I have removed that link

Comment: It is already hopeless to determine $s(p)$ for EVERY prime $p$ upto , say , $p=10^{50}$ since the number of primes upto $10^{50}$  is just too large. I expect another $4$-chain  far below $p=10^{50}$ , but that does not mean that it is easy to find it and I did not yet make a concrete estimate where the next $4$-chain might be.

Comment: If  computer programming have the capacity to check prime number upto $10^50$then it is probably impossible to check value upto S( $10^50$ ) but however if you check S(P) such that it last terms is $10^50$ then probably your computer programming work there....

Comment: Here symbols $10^50$ means 10 raised to power 50...,